# Laravel Dynamic Mailserver [Laravel 6.2]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

im currently trying to figure out, how to conditionally change the mailserver.
The Mail is a Notification, which gets send via the queue worker.
I tried multiple approaches such as: Setting the Config dynamically with `Config::set`, using a Middleware and removing the MailserviceProvider etc.
But the Mail still gets send out via the mailserver that is set in the .env.
I debugged the whole Job until it finishes, and it still had the mailserver which i set dynamically (Checked via `Config::get('mail')`). But it still gets not send out with this one.

I hope you can help me, thanks!

Comment: This was actually built into the framework as a feature as of Laravel 7. If you have the possibility to upgrade to Laravel 7 or 8 you can use that: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#sending-mail-via-a-specific-mailer

Comment: @RojVroemen sadly, i currently have no option to upgrade to laravel 7, is there any known method to do this in laravel 6?

Comment: I only have a really dirty workaround, I'll post it as an answer so I can format it correctly

Answer (score 0):

This would be a workaround but I'd really recommend you to upgrade your install to Laravel 8 whenever you have the chance.

You could place this code in a middleware, a simple function or anywhere else where you need it.

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

// Change your mail configuration
config()->set('mail.from.address', 'changed@foo.test'); // You probably want to change more than just the from address ;)


// Clear all instances
Mail::clearResolvedInstance('mailer');
Mail::clearResolvedInstance('swift.mailer');
Mail::clearResolvedInstance('swift.transport');
App::forgetInstance('mailer');
App::forgetInstance('swift.mailer');
App::forgetInstance('swift.transport');
```

Comment: Sadly this also doesnt work for me, it seems like, the values get set somewhere else, way before i change it dynamically like so. Do you have any idea where this could be? It may be the same moment, when i start the queue.

Comment: Do you change the config before queueing the mail or in the queued job itself? Changing it before queueing probably does not work as these settings are not persisted in any way

Comment: Im changing it in the queued job itself at runtime, and the config('mail') attributes are the right ones (debugged it through). Thats why i dont understand why it still gets send via the old server.